# How do I input many Exam Package TeX files into a main TeX file?

Tags: packages, exam, document

I may need some help here with how to input many TeX documents into a big TeX document.

I created many folders for students as homework. It looks like below:

> [image]

> [image]

In each folder, there is a TeX document including the questions and solutions. But the type of the TeX document is the [Exam Package](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en).

I want to use a main tex to read all the TeX documents in the folders to compile a workbook for the students.

I am wondering how to do this. I tried a few solutions from the template on Overleaf. But it does not work. Can someone help me in providing the TeX codes for main tex to read each TeX document in each folders?

All the TeX files in the folders look like below:

```
\documentclass[11pt, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{esvect, tasks, xhfill}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,multicol,enumerate}

\usepackage[right=0.8in, left=0.5in, top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\alph{partno}}
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\thequestion.} %replace period with parenthesis
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\large\arabic{question}}
\footer{}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages\  }{}

\begin{document} 

\runningheader{}{\examnum\ - Page \thepage\ of \numpages}{\examdate}
\header{G11 1st term} {\quad \hspace*{2cm} \LARGE{\ct{{20221209 Homework}}}}{\Large\textbf{\# 23} } 
\runningheadrule
\vspace*{-0.5in}
\noindent\rule[0.25\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{1pt}
\vspace*{0.5em}
\noindent Chinese name: \underline{\hspace*{2.5cm}} English name:  \underline{\hspace*{2.5cm}}  Homeroom: \underline{\hspace*{1.5cm}}  Math Class: \underline{\hspace*{1.2cm}} 

\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{(\roman{subpart})}
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\thesubpart} 

\begin{questions}

\question Let $f(x)= \begin{cases}x^2, & x>3 \\ 5, & x=3 \\ 3 x, & x<3\end{cases}$
\begin{parts}
    \part Sketch the graph of $y=f(x)$.
    \part Evaluate $\lim _{x \rightarrow 3^{-}} f(x)$ and $\lim _{x \rightarrow 3^{+}} f(x)$.
    \part Does $\lim _{x \rightarrow 3} f(x)$ exist? Explain your answer.
\end{parts}

\begin{solutionordottedlines}[1.5in]
    %\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{solutions1}
\end{solutionordottedlines}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  If you've compiled each document, you can use `\includepdf` from `pdfpages`.  If you're wanting to `\input` the tex source for each document, you might need to use `\subfiles`, which would require adjusting the preambles that you're using.  Do you have an idea on which of those "ifs" you want to pursue?

Comment: @Teepeemm Hi Teepeemm, thank you so much. I would like to use the \subfiles so that it would be easy for me to adjust some problems. All all the TeX files in each folder have the same preambles. I just don't know how to write the main TeX to read each TeXfile in the folders. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked through the subfiles documentation?  You can type `texdoc subfiles` at a command line, or go to https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles?lang=en.  You can also look at Overleaf's documentation: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects#The_subfiles_package